# Debugging a Simple List Function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am going through some list functions and programming them in Scheme. I am doing this for fun. This is not a school/college assignment. It is humbling to realize that I am stumbling with very basic functions and statements!

To my surprise this `member?` function consistently raises an error, with more than one Scheme REPL reporting that I am trying to tap the non-function #t.

```
    (define member?
     (lambda (atm lst)
      (cond
        ((null? lst) #f)
        ((equal? atm (car lst)) #t)
        (else
          ((member? atm (cdr lst)))))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((member? atm (cdr lst)))
```

Assuming `(member? atm (cdr lst))` evaluates to `#t`, the above is equivalent to `(#t)`, so it tries to apply `#t` as a function, which is what the error message is telling you.

Remove the outer parentheses and you'll get the result you want.